# Sharing git repo on NTFS partition between Linux/Windows dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, ntfs, git

I've posted this question already stackoverflow but got no answer: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752726/sharing-git-repo-on-ntfs-partition-between-linux-windows-dualboot)

Since I'm having this problem on Ubuntu I repost my question here. I hope this is not forbidden.

> I'm developing an (Qt) application which should run under Windows and Linux. So, I want to be able to develop under Windows and Linux, too.
>
> Therefore I have stored my project (as git repo) on a NTFS partition which I mount under Linux (Ubuntu 13.10). To avoid the rights problem of the compiled executable I set the shadow build directory to my home folder under Linux.
>
> This approach work quit good so far. But there are some effects that make me worry: If I stage some changed files (with smartgit), smartgit doesn't reflect that I have stage them. They are still displayed as unstaged.
>
> Similar thing when commiting: After the commit, the commited changes are still display as if they where not commit. But in the log I can see they are commited. Closing an reopen the repo "solves" this issues or is a workaround at least.
>
> But I have concerns that I break my repo using it on a NTFS partition under Linux. Or is there no risk that my repo is getting corrupted one day using it that way?

Comment: You don't need Git repository sharing on the HDD. Just clone the repository again.

Comment: The repo is just local. So I have to share it on HDD. What I've currently done as workaround is mounted the NTFS partition on Ubuntu and cloned the repo to my home folder. But this results in unnecessary pull/push actions. And I have the same concerns breaking the (remote) repo by pushing to a NTFS partition on Linux. So using the same repo on both systems would provide a smoother workflow...

Comment: Why not make a private repository on BitBucket (it's free)?

Comment: Not allowed by my business policy... And the problem with unnecessary pull/push actions is the same, plus Internet connection would be required....

Comment: Maybe to make another partition that both file systems will see?

Comment: You mean a new FAT32 partition? Would be a little cumbersome because the shared project would be in another place than all the other projects under Windows. Or I would have to move all projects to new location. Not very nice, too. But in general: What is your option on using a git repo on a NTFS partition under Ubuntu? Is it dangerous?

Comment: I just have Git repos on each system, I don't like sharing over NTFS.

Answer (score 5):

that happens because of the file mode. Windows and linux write files differently, so for both of them the files are constantly "new". type this in your directory:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

and the filesystem changes will dissapear from your index.

Comment: Note that on Linux, that command will fail with `error: chmod on .git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted`, so it's necessary to edit `.git/config` file manually. Even after that it's still not possible to run `git config`.